# Homebrew - Maven version remains same even after changing

Tags: homebrew

I am executing the following commands on my Mac Terminal:
`brew unlink maven@3.5`
It shows: Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven@3.5/3.5.4_1...  3 symlinks removed
`brew link maven`
It shows: Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.6... 3 symlinks created
`mvn --version`
Apache Maven 3.5.4

Even though it shows that it's linked to 3.8.6. When I run `mvn --version` command
it shows the version 3.5.4. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You have several versions. `which mvn` should tell you where your current one is found

Comment: `which mvn` outputs /opt/homebrew/opt/maven/bin/mvn

Comment: Then this is a home brew problem. Not a maven probkem